# Fluentbit sidecar not sending logs

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, datadog, fluent-bit

I have a setup in an ECS service ( Fargate ), with a firelens sidecar container to send logs to Datadog. Here is the Terraform code ( using this module https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws/latest )

```
container_definitions = {
    gtm = {
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 2048
      essential = true
      image     = "gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable"

      log_configuration = {
        logDriver = "awsfirelens"
        options = {
          Name        = "datadog",
          Host        = "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu",
          TLS         = "on",
          apikey      = <Datadog API KEY>,
          dd_service  = "sstgjms",
          dd_source   = "gtm",
          dd_tags     = "project:gtm",
          provider    = "ecs",
          retry_limit = "2"
        }
      }

      dependencies = [{
        containerName = "log_router"
        condition     = "START"
      }]

      enable_cloudwatch_logging = false
      memory_reservation        = 100
    }

    log_router = {
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 2048
      essential = true
      image     = "amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest"

      firelens_configuration = {
        type = "fluentbit"
        options = {
          enable-ecs-log-metadata = "true"
        }
      }

      environment = [
        {
          name  = "FLB_LOG_LEVEL"
          value = "debug"
        }
      ]

      log_configuration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group         = "sstgjms"
          awslogs-region        = "eu-central-1"
          awslogs-create-group  = "true"
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "stream"
        }
      }

      enable_cloudwatch_logging = false
      memory_reservation        = 50
    }

  }
```

In the logs of the sidecar, I don't see any warning or error logs:

```
[debug] [output:datadog:datadog.1] https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu, port=443, HTTP status=202 payload={}  log_router
[debug] [upstream] KA connection #53 to http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu:443 is now available  log_router
[debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=20   log_router
[debug] [task] destroy task=0x7f81e944a430 (task_id=0)  log_router
[debug] [http_client] not using http_proxy for header   log_router
[debug] [net] socket #53 could not connect to 2600:1901:0:8cd6:::443    log_router
[debug] [task] created task=0x7f81e944a430 id=0 OK  log_router
[debug] [input chunk] update output instances with new chunk size diff=505  log_router
[debug] [upstream] drop keepalive connection #-1 to http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu:443 (keepalive idle timeout)  log_router
[debug] [socket] could not validate socket status for #53 (don't worry) log_router
```

I feel like I'm have a wrong misconfiguration somewhere, an obvious one that I'm missing but going through the Datadog documentation, I couldn't find anything. Could someone please check with me ?